# No timing breakdown in User Timing section in Performance tab in Chrome dev tools using React 16

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I was following this article: https://calibreapp.com/blog/2017-11-28-debugging-react/

I run the profiling but when I click on the the component, I can't see the exact timing, as is mentioned in the article.

I use React 16, I'm in development mode. I also tried `?react_perf` but that didn't help (that should be for React 15 anyway)

[image]

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the current stable release of Chrome. Using a newer version of Chrome, such as [Chrome Dev](https://www.google.com/intl/en_au/chrome/dev/) or Canary, will allow you to use the breakdown until the update makes its way into a stable release of Chrome.

Sources:

- [React Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14067)
- [Associated Chromium Forum Post](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901418#c1)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using React v17 or greater, note these timings have been removed from React: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18417.

Comment: The User Timing API was removed, because of Inaccurate timings, Insufficient programmatic API, Bugs and maintenance burden. As an alternative the [`<React.Profiler>` component](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html#performance-measurements-with-reactprofiler) was added.